# Solve $\cos 2x-\cos 3x+\sin 4x = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots, closed-form, factoring

Solve Equation$$\cos 2x-\cos 3x+\sin 4x=0 $$

Attemp:Developping up to $\sin x,\cos x$, equation is :

$(\cos x-1)(4\cos^2x+2\cos x-1)=4\sin x(2\cos^3x-\cos x)$
Note that squaring will give solutions $x_i$ such that either $x_i$, either $-x_i$ is solution of the current equation.

So $(\cos x-1)^2(4\cos^2x+2\cos x-1)^2=16(1-\cos^2x)(2\cos^3x-\cos x)^2$

We obviously get $\cos x=1$ (which indeed is a solution of original equation) and it remains
$(1-\cos x)(4\cos^2x+2\cos x-1)^2=16(1+\cos x)(2\cos^3x-\cos x)^2$

Setting $\cos x=y$, this is :
$(1-y)(4y^2+2y-1)^2=16(1+y)(2y^3-y)^2$
Which is $64y^7+64y^6-48y^5-64y^4-4y^3+16y^2+5y-1=0$

I found no clever way to solve this degree-7 polynomial

Comment: I don't think there is a clever way to solve this. [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Ccos+2x-%5Ccos+3x%2B%5Csin+4x%3D0) provides rather *Ugly* solutions.

Comment: Wat suggests this equation has a closed form solution?

Comment: @conditionalMethod Isn't that for $\cos+\cos+\cos$? Surely for this equation, we would have $\frac{z^{2}+z^{-2}}{2}-\frac{z^{3}+z^{-3}}{2}+\frac{z^{4}-z^{-4}}{2i}=0$, so $z^{8}-iz^{7}+iz^{6}+iz^{2}-iz^{1}-1=0$.

Comment: @Jam Yes, I read the last $\sin$ as a $\cos$.

Comment: The solutions [don't admit](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+cos%282x%29-cos%283x%29%2Bsin%284x%29%3D0) a nice description, never mind a nice derivation.

Comment: Check you polynomial I obtain $64 y^8 - 112 y^6 - 16 y^5 + 60 y^4 + 20 y^3 - 11 y^2 - 6 y + 1 = 0$

Comment: From where did that problem arise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [tangent half angle identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) we obtain by $t=\tan \frac x 2$

- $\cos 2x =2\cos^2 x-1=\frac{2(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}-1$
- $\cos 3x=4\cos^3 x-3\cos x=4\frac{(1-t^2)^3}{(1+t^2)^3}-3\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$
- $\sin (4x)=2\sin (2x)\cos(2x)=4\sin x\cos x(2\cos^2 x-1)=4\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\left(\frac{2(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}-1\right)$

then

$$\cos 2x-\cos 3x+\sin 4x=0$$

$$\frac{2(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}-1-4\frac{(1-t^2)^3}{(1+t^2)^3}+3\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+4\frac{2t}{1+t^2}\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\left(\frac{2(1-t^2)^2}{(1+t^2)^2}-1\right)=0$$

$$2(1-t^2)^2(1+t^2)^2-(1+t^2)^4-4(1-t^2)^3(1+t^2)+$$$$+3(1-t^2)(1+t^2)^3+8t(1-t^2)(t^4-6t^2+1)=0$$

that is

$$t (t^7 - 4 t^6 - 9 t^5 + 28 t^4 - 5 t^3 - 28 t^2 + 5 t + 4) = 0$$

which confirms that $t=0$ is a solution then

$$t^7 - 4 t^6 - 9 t^5 + 28 t^4 - 5 t^3 - 28 t^2 + 5 t + 4=0$$

which seems to have others $5$ not trivial [solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+t%5E7+-+4+t%5E6+-+9+t%5E5+%2B+28+t%5E4+-+5+t%5E3+-+28+t%5E2+%2B+5+t+%2B+4%3D0).

Comment: I'm confused how you've got $6$ roots when the previously mentioned polynomial ($64y^7+64y^6-48y^5-64y^4-4y^3+16y^2+5y-1=0$) has $7$. Is one of the roots superfluous?

Comment: There is something wrong with your polynomial since we should obtain also y=1 as solution. I check that.

Comment: Choosing $t=\tan\frac x2$ or $y=\cos x$ are two different paths, quite OK both.

I did not check your progression here above but it seems to me that the final quintic does not have formal solution. :(

Comment: @MeuluElisson Yes indeed unfourtanately [quintic equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html) can't be solved algebrically, we need numerical methods.

Comment: Regarding my earlier point, I think the higher degree of the polynomial in $y$ is just due to inclusion of extra complex roots that aren't solutions. But even still, I get sensible roots from Meulu's $y$-polynomial but not User's. e.g. $y=0.143\Rightarrow x=\cos^{-1}0.143=4.86$ is a root but  $t=-0.880\Rightarrow x=\tan^{-1} 2t$ is not. So I think you might have an algebra error but I agree with your methodology.

Comment: @MeuluElisson Anyway check your polynomial it seems there is some mistake in the derivation but your method is fine. Of course by tangent hal formula we reduce to a quintic which is simpler. In general the use of tangent half angle identities is good to obtain such kind of solutions.

Comment: @user I think I've found the error. So we have $\cos x = \frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$ but when you calculated $\cos 2x$, you had $2\cos(x)^2-1=2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-1$, which should have been $2\left(\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}\right)^{\color{red}{2}}-1$.

Comment: @Jam Thanks a lot I check that and I fix all the derivation.

Comment: @Jam Now it should be fixed!

Comment: Using the tangent half-angle substitution, i got $2 t \left(t^7-4 t^6-9 t^5+28 t^4-5 t^3-28 t^2+5 t+4\right)$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks Claude! I check it again.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Indeed I see now that I forgot a square! Thanks I fix it

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici FInally I find your result! Thanks again

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I also think there is a mistake for the polynomial in the OP. Can you check it too? Thanks

Comment: It is very correct.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this has to be solved numerically using Newton method. Graphing for $0 \leq x \leq 2\pi$, we can notice, beside the trivial roots $x=0$ and $x=2\pi$, solutions close to $1.0$, $2.7$, $3.8$, $4.9$ and $5.6$.

Using these as starting points, Newton iterates are 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1.00000 \\
 1 & 0.95437 \\
 2 & 0.95541
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 2.70000 \\
 1 & 2.72792 \\
 2 & 2.72687 \\
 3 & 2.72687
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 3.80000 \\
 1 & 3.84203 \\
 2 & 3.84161
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 4.90000 \\
 1 & 4.85398 \\
 2 & 4.85570 \\
 3 & 4.85571
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 5.60000 \\
 1 & 5.66083 \\
 2 & 5.66212 \\
 3 & 5.66213
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Factorirzing your given equation we get
$$2 \sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \left(\sqrt{2} \sin
   \left(\frac{5 x}{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\cos
   \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{3
   x}{2}\right)+\cos \left(\frac{7 x}{2}\right)\right)=0$$

Comment: How do you always factor these *ugly equations* so fast ?

Comment: Show some work, please. :)

Comment: $$\cos(2x)=2\cos^2(x)-1$$

Comment: $$\cos(x)=2\cos^2(x/2)-1$$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit All his answers come from WolframAlpha.

Comment: What make you think that this new equation is simpler than $\cos 2x-\cos 3x+\sin 4x=0$ ?

I would be very happy if you could show us how your hint make us nearer of the solution ....

Comment: @MeuluElisson It gives you some of the solutions, when $\sin(x/2)=0$.

Comment: The OP already had these factors: they knew that $(1-\cos x)$ was a factor, which is the same roots as $\sin\frac{x}{2}$. This doesn't add anything.

Comment: Ohh sorry,
I thought that this was a hint to get a formal expression for the five other real roots.

Note that your solution $\sin\frac x2$ is the one I got two lines below ($\cos x=1$).
The real problem is, in my opinion, to find the nontrivial real roots...